# Limiting number of features loaded by QGIS2Leaf?

Tags: leaflet, qgis2leaf

I'm using the QGIS2Leaf plugin. [As others have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567378/efficient-way-of-accessing-large-data-sets-to-display-on-leaflet), Leaflet slows down when the number of features becomes too large.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567378/efficient-way-of-accessing-large-data-sets-to-display-on-leaflet

I've worked out how to limit zoom levels, and have the map load zoomed right in. I'm now trying to work out how to just load the features within those bounds, and have the load refresh as the user pans to change those bounds.

Could anyone familiar with Leaflet/QGIS2Leaf tell me if this is possible, and further how to achieve it?

Comment: What kind of QGIS layers are they? I'm asking because, as far as I understand it, this can only work with remote data (eg WFS), and not with embedded GeoJSON. Also, it's not something qgis2leaf supports at the moment, and I'm not sure I can see it being developed - sorry. However, if you can give us some more details about what format your original data is in, that will help.